# PHP ftp_nlist() returning bool(false) even with passive mode and different users

Tags: php, ftp

I'm currently making a script that will backup files that I have on my server but am having a major issue. About 30 minutes ago I was able to connect using the same script, list my files, and download them. But now when I try to connect, it connects and that is it, I can't `ftp_nlist` the files because when I do it just returns `bool(false)`. I read on some other posts that I should try setting passive mode to true with `ftp_pasv` but it did not change anything. I've also tried other users which do the same exact thing. I tried using the credentials on filezilla and it connected and allowed me to download with no issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'll post the code below.

PHP:

Connect to FTP

```
$ftp_server = "Hidden for security";
$ftp_user = "Hidden for security";
$ftp_pass = "Hidden for security";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Get filenames on FTP

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
$rm = array(0, 1, 2, 3,);
foreach($rm as $value) {
    unset($contents[$value]);
}
$contents = array_values($contents);
```

Get filenames on localhost

```
$dir = scandir("images/");
$rmval = array(0, 1, 2);
foreach ($rmval as $val) {
    unset($dir[$val]);
}
$dir = array_values($dir);
```

Try to login

```
if (ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    //echo "Connected";
    $counter = 0;
    var_dump($contents);

    /*foreach ($ftp_content as $file) {
        ftp_get($conn_id, "images/" . $ftp_content[$counter], $ftp_content[$counter], FTP_BINARY);
        $counter++;
    }*/
} else {
    echo "Couldn't Connect";
}
```

Close FTP connection

```
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to list my files before establishing a connection to the FTP server. Adding `$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)` after `$conn_id` fixed my issue. Now I'm able to evaluate if it's true or false and run different code depending on the result.